# False negative for well known relay

Tags: torcheck

https://check.torproject.org/ told me that I wasn't using Tor. So I checked the IP and it was listed on

- https://metrics.torproject.org/rs
- https://metrics.torproject.org/exonerator.html
- https://check.torproject.org/exit-addresses

The relay was active and had an uptime of several weeks. Why would the check give a false negative for a well known relay? Nothing changed when checking again after some waiting.

Comment: Were you using the official Tor Browser?

Comment: @Steve: Yes of course Sorry but I couldn't reply with a "comment" hence this "answer"

Comment: @checkerer It looks like you have two accounts, which is why you couldn't comment. If you fill out the form [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/contact), we can look at fixing that for you. :)